# git checkout to restore files from a prior branch: pathspec did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

I deleted some files from git and now want them back.  I am trying to use `git checkout` to restore the files.

I looked back through my history, and identified the commit where the files were deleted.  When I run `git checkout <sha of deleting commit> path/to/my/file`, I get

`error: pathspec 'path/to/my/file' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Doh.  The commit that deleted those files would necessarily not have them anymore.  Thus, I need to go one commit further back.  Running:

`git checkout <sha of deleting commit>^ path/to/my/file`

works perfectly

Comment: for what does the `^` stand for? one further back?